# Sort result texts in PyQt by key value

Tags: python, loops, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort my output results from my program in PyQt using a sort of key value then print out the text that correspond to the order.

In other words I have this piece of code:

```
with open(compareResults, 'wb') as fdout:
            for index, tabName in enumerate(setNames):
                tabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
                tabLabel = QtGui.QTextEdit()
                print "Tab Name is :{}".format(tabName)
                fdout.write('{}'.format(tabName) + '\r\n')

                nameData = lst[index]
                print 'name data = {}'.format(nameData)
                for k in nameData:
                    if k in correct_parameters:
                        if nameData[k] != correct_parameters[k]:
                            tabLabel.setTextColor(QtGui.QColor("Red"))
                            tabLabel.append('This Parameter is Incorrect: {} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                            fdout.write('\t' + '|' + 'This Parameter is Incorrect: {} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]) + '\t' + '|' + '\r\n')
                            print ('{} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                            tabCounter+=1

                        elif nameData[k] == correct_parameters[k]:
                            tabLabel.setTextColor(QtGui.QColor("Black"))
                            tabLabel.append('{} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                            fdout.write('\t' + '|' + '{} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]) + '\t' + '|' + '\r\n')

                            print ('{} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                    else:
                        tabLabel.setTextColor(QtGui.QColor("Blue"))
                        tabLabel.append('{} = {} does not appear in our default'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                        fdout.write('\t' + '|' + '{} = {} does not appear in our default'.format(k, nameData[k]) + '\t' + '|' + '\r\n')
                        print ('{} = {} does not appear in our default'.format(k, nameData[k]))
                        tabCounter += 1
                tabLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
                tabLayout.addWidget(tabLabel)
                tabWidget.setLayout(tabLayout)
                self.tabWidget.addTab(tabWidget, tabName)
                if tabCounter == 0:
                    print 'no change in tabs'
```

The program prints out line by line of the result in this case, what am aiming to do is print out the lines in order from `nameData[k] != correct_parameters[k]` then `nameData[k] == correct_parameters[k]` and then `else`

So my idea was to assign a key value to each one of these lines, so if the information is incorrect I can assign a key value of 0, then if the line is correct the key value is 1, and if the line doesn't appear it will have a key value of 2. Then I can sort those values in order numerically from 0-2. and print them out to the tabs im creating.

So far I understand how to assign the keyvalue to the three different situations I have here the issue is creating a `tabLabel.append` with the key values in order.

I was thinking of using something along the lines of this pseudo code: 
for keyvalue in storedvalues:
for all keys equal to 0 print
then for all keys equal to 1 print
and then for all keys equal to 2 print.

Although I'm not sure if, rather than using a loop, I could instead store each result into a new dictionary then assign those keys to the value in the dictionary and just use a sort method like `sorted(data.values())` in this case. Then after sorting print out the dictionary.